# Manipulating the results of multiple AJAX Calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm performing two separate AJAX calls and I'd ultimately like for the results to be in the form of a number variable that I can manipulate. I've wrapped the execution of the functions within $(function() in an attempt to wait until both of the AJAX functions have returned their value so as not to begin to do the math before the results are returned, but it appears that's not working.

How can I ensure that the results are returned from two separate AJAX calls before the function manipulates their results?

```js
// Collect Data Point P
function myCallbackP(result) {
 var p = Math.round(result/3);
    $('#past').html(p);
}

fooP(myCallbackP);
function fooP (callback){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'https://' + company + '.teamwork.com/' + actionP,
  headers: {"Authorization": "BASIC " + window.btoa(key)},
 }).done(function(response){
  callback((response['todo-items']).length);
   })
}

//Collect Data Point F
function myCallbackF(result) {
 var f = (result);
    $('#future').html(f);
}
fooF(myCallbackF);
function fooF (callback){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'https://' + company + '.teamwork.com/' + actionF,
  headers: {"Authorization": "BASIC " + window.btoa(key)},
 }).done(function(response){
  callback((response['todo-items']).length);
   })
}

//Math up data point P and F
$(function() {
    var v = myCallbackP();
  var y =myCallbackP;
  var z = v/y;
  console.log(z);
  $('#ratio').html(z);
  console.log('success?');
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Comment: You can use promises. Please take a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Are you trying to call `callback` when request succeeds, or wait until both requests succeed before processing result of both requests?

Comment: You can have a boolean that's initialy false, set it to true on the first callback, and if it's true, you are in your second callback. (A promise.all() would be better but not all browsers support it)

Comment: @guest271314 I'm using callback to retrieve the results of each request.

Comment: `y =myCallbackP;` this makes `y` a reference to your `myCallbackP`  function, so using it in the math operation `var z = v/y;` makes no sense. Also `$(function)` does not wait for AJAX functions to finish, it is for running a function when the document is ready for use

Comment: Thanks, @PatrickEvans. That's what I was worried about. Is $.when() or Deferred/Promises a better avenue then?  I've been reading about getScript... could I use that as a way to ensure this script is executed before the page is loaded somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.when()`

```
// Collect Data Point P
function myCallbackP(result) {
  var p = Math.round(result / 3);
  $('#past').html(p);
}

function fooP(callback) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://' + company + '.teamwork.com/' + actionP,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "BASIC " + window.btoa(key)
    }
  })
}

//Collect Data Point F
function myCallbackF(result) {
  var f = (result);
  $('#future').html(f);
}

function fooF(callback) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://' + company + '.teamwork.com/' + actionF,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "BASIC " + window.btoa(key)
    }
  })
}

//Math up data point P and F
$(function() {
  $.when(fooP(), fooF())
  .then(function(p, f) {
    console.log('success?');
    myCallbackP(p[0]["todo-items"].length);
    myCallbackF(f[0]["todo-items"].length);
     var v = +$("#past").html();
     var y = +$("#future").html();
     var z = v / y;
     console.log(z);
    $('#ratio').html(z);
  })
  .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log(errorThrown);
  });

  console.log("ready!");
});
```

Comment: Hmm. I'm getting an error on the 5th line in this block:
`$(function() {
  $.when(fooP(), fooF())
  .then(function(p, f) {
    console.log('success?');
    myCallbackP(p["todo-items"].length);
    myCallbackF(f["todo-items"].length);
     var v = +$("#past").html();
     var y = +$("#future").html();
     var z = v / y;
     console.log(z);
    $('#ratio').html(z);
  })
  .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log(errorThrown);
  });`

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Array.<anonymous> (ajaxquerytest3.html:49)

Comment: You removed `[0]` following `p` and `f` at `myCallbackP` and `myCallbackF` calls? `p` and `f` are arrays. What does `console.log(p[0], f[0])` log at `console`?

Comment: Not sure what happened there. Reconstructed with exactly what you have above and I didn't receive a console error but the result of `console(z)` was NaN so I reconstructed the `url` variables manually to confirm the still return the correct items and they do. Hrmm...

Comment: What does `console.log(p[0]["todo-items"].length, f[0]["todo-items"].length)` log? Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?

Comment: It logs 170, the correct number. I'll get to work on a jsfiddle.

Comment: There should be two numbers logged, yes? If the correct number is logged, what is the issue?

Comment: Aha! The issue was that it wasn't printing. Turns out I had an issue in my HTML preventing var z from showing correctly. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use jQuery `Deferred` and `Promises` like below

```js
var ajax1 = fooP();

function fooP() {
  var defObj = $.Deferred();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://' + company + '.teamwork.com/' + actionP,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "BASIC " + window.btoa(key)
    },
  }).done(function(response) {
    defObj.resolve(response);
  });
  return defObj.promise();
}


var ajax2 = fooF();

function fooF() {
  var defObj = $.Deferred();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://' + company + '.teamwork.com/' + actionF,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "BASIC " + window.btoa(key)
    },
  }).done(function(response) {
    defObj.resolve(response);
  });

  return defObj.promise();
}


// when both calls are done
$.when(ajax1, ajax2).done(function(data1, data2) {
  var p = Math.round(data1 / 3);
  $('#past').html(p);

  var f = (data2);
  $('#future').html(f);

  var z = p / f;
  console.log(z);
  $('#ratio').html(z);
  console.log('success?');
  console.log("ready!");

});
```

Comment: `$.Deferred()` is not necessary. `jQuery.ajax()` returns a jQuery promise object.

Comment: Agreed. I was more comfortable doing it this way. :)

Comment: OK, so I'm getting an undefined response and no console logging of success or ready. I've edited the above to console log (p) right after we perform the Math.round() on it and I'm not getting anything there either.